# My TableView's not changed after reload data

Tags: swift, tableview, reload

I wrote a class that let me create multiple tableView simply. When I call this class for the first time, everything work well. But when I change some data, and reload the table, nothing changed.

Sample code:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    var arrData = ["a","b","c"]
    var myTableView: MyTableView?
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        myTableView = MyTableView(table: tableView, data: arrData)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        arrData = ["d","e","f"]
        myTableView!.tableView.reloadData() //=> Not change anything
    }
}


class MyTableView: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView: UITableView
    var data: Array<String>

    init(table: UITableView, data: Array<String>) {
        self.data = data
        self.tableView = table
        super.init()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        self.tableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }



    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = self.data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}


class MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    //something here
}
```

When the view was loaded, the table has 3 rows: a,b,c. When I tap the button, nothing changed (expected: d,e,f)

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift arrays are copied by value so the line `self.data = data` will take a copy of your array. Later changing the array contents of the source will not be reflected in the copy in your `MyTableView`.

You'll need to pass the array over again and take a second copy to update the table, e.g. write a method in `MyTableView` similar to the following:-

```
func setNewValues(data: Array<String>)
{ 
  self.data = data
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and call that from your `buttonTapped` function, i.e.:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    arrData = ["d","e","f"]
    myTableView!.setNewValues(data: arrData)
}
```

Be careful with the force-unwrapped `myTableView` though - I'd replace that '!' with '?'.

Comment: Work like a charm. You saved ton of hours for me. Thank you so much!